# Import data from Excel into existing table

Tags: sql-server

I have a table `HRTC` in SQL Server. I want to import data which is in Excel into this table. But my Excel file does not have all the columns which match the `HRTC` table. Is there anyway I can do this?

I am thinking something like in the import wizard

```
Insert into SQLServerTable Select * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')

 select column1, column2 from HRTC
```

Comment: Can you provide structures of your tables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

Create a temp table

```
Select * INTO TmpTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')
```

Then to insert row into hrtc using temptable, any missing columns will have null

```
INSERT INTO hrtc(column1, column2)
select col1, col2 from TmpTable
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Should i import the spreatsheet into sql under [sheetName$] first? Where should i put code Select * INTO TmpTable FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 
'Excel 8.0;Database=D:\testing.xls;HDR=YES', 
'SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]')    sql statement of import wizard? sorry i am just begining

Comment: you can run this code in sql window and you can import that into any table just replace TmpTable with name you want to use

Comment: so there is no direct approach? I mean update desired table directly?

Answer (score 1):

One simple approach is to script your excel file into a collection of insert statement, then run it on SQL Server.

Also if you can export your excel file into CSV file, this is often useful. Tool like SQL Server Management Studio should have some kind of import wizard where you can load the CSV, choose column mapping etc.

Comment: I do use SQL Server Management Studio , but i can not load csv, the only choose is excel,access and others....

Comment: According to this MSDN doc you can import excel and flat file: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms140052.aspx

Comment: sorry, I find it flat file now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What I often end up doing in these situations is to do some code completion using excel's CONCATENATE function.

Let's say you have:

```
     A     B
1  foo     bar
2  test2   bar2
3  test3   bar 3
```

If you needed to insert those into a table. In column C you can write:

```
=CONCATENATE("INSERT INTO HRTC(col, col2) VALUES('", A1, "','", B1, "')")
```